# Node on GAE Flex getting max listener issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-app-engine

I run my code on a dev server to test the project, and it runs fine without this issue happening. I recently added verbose logging to my project to find out where this warning is coming from and it looks like the warning has been traced back to this stack output. Does anyone have any ideas where this is caused in GAE Flex?

> (node:16) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 wakeup listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
>
> ```
>  at _addListener (events.js:280:19)
>
>  at Connection.addListener (events.js:297:10)
>
>  at Connection.Readable.on (_stream_readable.js:772:35)
>
>  at Connection.once (events.js:341:8)
>
>  at Connection._send (/app/node_modules/http2/lib/protocol/connection.js:355:10)
>
>  at runCallback (timers.js:810:20)
>
>  at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:768:5)
>
>  at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:745:5)
> ```

Comment: any ideas on how to fix this issue?